# NGINX redirection to www domain does not work

Tags: nginx

I have an mywebsite.conf that is included in the nginx.conf. The file is like this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.mywebsite.nl;
    return 301 https://www.mywebsite.nl$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mywebsite.nl;
    return 301 https://www.mywebsite.nl$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name mywebsite.nl;
    ...
    return 301 https://www.mywebsite.nl$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name www.mywebsite.nl;
    ...
}
```

This config works for all of my websites. But somehow this time the http://mywebsite.nl does not redirect to https://www.mywebsite.nl.

I can't find out why. DNS is pointing to the server. Caches are incognito.

I reloaded and restarted nginx. Tried fresh browsers. Used https://wheregoes.com to test it.

Any ideas?

The output of curl is:

```
* Trying 37.97.xxx.xx...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to mywebsite.nl (37.97.xxx.xx) port 80 (#0)
> HEAD / HTTP/1.1
> Host: mywebsite.nl
> User-Agent: curl/7.64.1
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)
Server: nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)
< Date: Wed, 14 Jul 2021 05:55:03 GMT
Date: Wed, 14 Jul 2021 05:55:03 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html
Content-Type: text/html
< Content-Length: 612
Content-Length: 612
< Last-Modified: Wed, 17 Apr 2019 18:42:45 GMT
Last-Modified: Wed, 17 Apr 2019 18:42:45 GMT
< Connection: keep-alive
Connection: keep-alive
< ETag: "5cb773a5-264"
ETag: "5cb773a5-264"
< Accept-Ranges: bytes
Accept-Ranges: bytes
```

Comment: are you able to add the output of `curl -Iv http://mywebsite.nl`. That would be good in the first round.

Comment: @TimoStark I edited my question with the output.

Comment: Thanks. So this looks like something else is processing your request and sends a http200. Just to start troubleshooting. `dig A mywebsite.nl` or `nslookup mywebsite.nl`. Just to be sure the DNS is pointing to the right server. If so check the whole nginx configuration for the server_name (Should print an warning if doubled) but worth checking.

Comment: I tried the above -> all good.

Then I tried: `grep -rn '/etc/nginx' -e 'mywebsite.nl'`

And I found that Certbot automatically added some lines to default.conf. So the server conf was indeed doubled. I remove those lines and now all is good.

Comment: there you go :) thats what I have thought. Glad to hear it is working now.